# Cannot find module '/home/backend/dist/src/server.js' with Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

Very new to Docker but When trying to run the container after building I get the following error, has anyone ran into this before?

```
'internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
throw err;'
^

'Error: Cannot find module '/home/backend/dist/src/server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []'
```

I have built without docker and seems to work fine I run the following commands against the dockerfile (below):

`docker build -t [name] .`

`docker run [name]`

```
 FROM node:14.17.1 as base
 WORKDIR /home/backend
 //Add package file
 COPY package.json ./
 COPY yarn.lock ./
 //Install deps
 RUN yarn install

 //Copy source
 COPY src ./src
 COPY tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json

 //Build dist
 RUN yarn build

 //Start production image build
 FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:14

 //Copy node modules and build directory
 COPY --from=base /home/backend/dist ./home/backend/dist

 //Expose port 5000
 EXPOSE 5000
 CMD [ "/home/backend/dist/src/server.js" ]
```

Comment: Is there really a `src` folder inside your `dist` folder?

Comment: Yes I have checked its `dist/src/`

Comment: `COPY --from=base /home/backend/dist ./home/backend/dist` this is maybe the issue? This seems like it's copying from `/home/backend/dist` on your computer to `/home/backend/home/backend/dist` (since you're at `/home/backend` already)

Comment: Silly mistake from me, thanks!